# Is there a function to sum every group of 7 cells?

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

For example, I have a column where I want each cell to be sum of 7 cells. So the first cell I want to Sum A1:A7, next cell I sum A8:A14 and next cell A15:A21 and so on. How can I do that without having to type in Axx:Axx for every cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=INDEX(QUERY({ROUNDUP(SEQUENCE(ROWS(A:A), 1)/7), A:A}, 
 "select sum(Col2) 
  where Col2 is not null 
  group by Col1 
  label sum(Col2)''"))
```

[image]